# how do sites keep runing even after hundreds if not thousands of errors?

Tags: javascript, html

sometimes i open the console in the site im visiting and i see A LOT of errors, not caused by console.error (that would not stop javascript), caused by true errors or throw (that should stop javascript), but, somehow, things (that need javascript) still seem to work, even after thousands of errors.

how does this happen?

Comment: `try/catch` lets you catch errors and do nothing about them.

Comment: Depending on the actual type of error it only stops the current running code stack. For instance one event listener may cause a variable undefined error, but that will not stop a different or even the same event listener to be run again. However a syntax error would prevent the script that it is in to be run, but wont prevent other scripts from loading and running

Comment: Patrick Evans i think that is the answer